# If a vector is bounded then its components are also bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

If $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $\lVert x \rVert < M$ for some $M > 0$.
I want to prove that its components are also bounded: $|x_1|, |x_2|, ..., |x_n| < N$ for some $N > 0$.

I already proved this assuming $\lVert x \rVert = \sqrt{ x_1^2 + x_2^2 ... + x_n^2}$, but is there a way to prove this without assuming a particular norm?

Comment: You can do that by using the fact that all norms in $\mathbb{R} ^n$ are equivalent to the Euclidean norm.

Comment: notice that $|x_i|\le \|x\|$ for every $i$

Comment: You don't need the hypothesis $\|x\| < M$: if $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$ then its components $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ are a finite set of real numbers and hence their moduli $|x_1|, \ldots, |x_n|$ have an upper bound.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this up as an answer because there has been some confusion in the comments. If $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$, so that $x = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ where each $x_i \in \Bbb{R}$, then the components of $x$ are bounded: $$x_i \le |x_i| \le |x_1| + |x_2| + \ldots + |x_n| < N$$
if we put $N = |x_1| + |x_2| + \ldots + |x_n| + 1$. This has nothing to do with any norm on $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @311411: that question makes sense, because it's about a sequence of vectors, not a single vector.

Comment: i guess the question here was a typo or misunderstanding from the very beginning. Both are asked by the same person.

Comment: @311411: I see. Not a very good way for the OP to proceed. This question should be closed, but unfortunately, after retracting one attempt to vote to close, MSE does not allow me to vote to close again.